# Android - Remove application from Recent Apps

Tags: android

I am developing an android application. If I close my application, my app available in the "Recent Apps" List. Now I don't want to show it in "Recent Apps". How can I remove it from "Recent Apps List" after closing my application programmatically. Please can you share your suggestions.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do it. What's the problem with that?

Comment: thanks. If I close my application after click home button, that activity will resume when I click it from Recent Apps. But I don't want to resume that activity. I want to start one default activity when the user clicks from Recent Apps.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In you `Manifest.xml`, set the following to your *Root Activity*

```
<activity
    android:name=".Your_Root_Activity_Name"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    .... 
</activity>
```

Depending on the results, you might also have to use the `android:noHistory="true"` attribute. But not sure if it is required in your case.

For more information about this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Answer (score 2):

Add `excludeFromRecents="true"` to your activity in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:excludeFromRecents="true" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

override the `onResume` methods in your other Activities and there destroy them and call the main Activity.

Comment: this answer is nonsense

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidManifest.xml, use this for Activity:

```
<activity
    android:name="Your Activity"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:taskAffinity="">
</activity>
```

Comment: explain how this XML answers the question